# RewriteRule not being tiggered on subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have [maybe] an unusual setup:

1. I have 1 storage/root folder with several domain and subdomains all
   pointing to the same folder.
2. I then create a subfolder for each domain or subdomain and us
   .htaccess to redirect the domain to the correct folder/files

Below is a working example of how i do this

```
# Domain1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^spain\.domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /spain/$1 [L]
```

This all works fine, HOWEVER:
If a user goes to doamin1.com/spain, they are of course presented with all files in that folder...

SO, i try to add a redirect just on the domain1.com/spain... yet this does not work... i have tried everything. including trying the redirect for the root .htaccess and the spain/.htaccess. Neither work.

I am trying the below (does not work)

```
# Domain1.com/spain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com/spain/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/? [L]
```

I have tried may variations of the above, but none seem to work (at all)

However the RedirectMatch does work (below) but also breaks the above subdomain (in the first example).

```
RedirectMatch ^/spain/$  /
```

if i try to match on more and add the RedirectMatch as (below) this then does not trigger the match...

```
RedirectMatch ^www\.domain1\.com/spain/$  /
```

I know what i need to do is possible (i think and assume), but im banging my head on walls here..... 
PLEASE advise and of course thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
# Domain1.com/spain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com/spain/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/? [L]
```

Because that last part (/spain) is NEVER part of the HTTP_HOST so it will never match :)

What you want to do is something like this

```
# Domain1.com/spain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^spain(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/? [R=302,NC,L]
```

In other words, to move the /spain part of the URL in RewriteRule where it is actually being matched and keep the domain name match in RewriteCond above.

Comment: there was glitch in RewriteRule it must be `^spain(.*)` and NOT `^/spain(.*)` - see updated answer

Comment: Thank you! I wish i could say it worked, but unfortunately it does not get triggered (i used your updated version). i have tried it in both the root and the /spain/ folder

Comment: So this link `http://domain1.com/spain/` is not redirecting to `http://www.domain1.com?` Or what URL are using to test?

Comment: (adult nature warning) http://my-local-escorts.co.uk/spain/ i have added the above code you suggest to both the root folder and the /spain/ folder and no, it is not redirecting (it does if i remove the spain in the RewriteRuel though, si i assume i am doing everything else OK)

Comment: Just tested locally and works for me. Those lines need to be just in the root folder of domain1.com and closer to the top so that they are checked first.

Comment: You need to edit/or remove the comment with the live link. And join me here to chat about your setup: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46568/chat-about-question

Comment: so it redirects you to http://www.my-local-escorts.co.uk/ from http://my-local-escorts.co.uk/spain/... hmm it is not for me... ill come to the chat room

Comment: to say, that the above did work!! it was down to a conflict i have in my .htaccess files